# Redirect user to another page after login auth and if statement with PHP PDO

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, pdo

I am trying to redirect the user to another page when login is successful and `$_SESSION[ 'logged_in' ] = true;`

However, current code doesn't seem to be working for whatever, everything seems okay logically. I am fairly new to php about two weeks so obviously I'm missing something. I've been looking around to see what I am doing wrong but still can't figure it out, so I am posting here as a last resort. I appreciate you taking the time to view my question.

This is my **login.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
//I have this on every single page. 

include ( 'PasswordHash.php' );
//I use this for password hashing
?>

<html>

<head>


 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <form name="login" action="login.php" method="POST">
        <label for "username">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
        <label for "password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/><br />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>


    <?php
    $username = $_POST[ 'username' ];
    //take username from form


    //start connection to database
    $user = 'xxxx';
    $pass = 'xxxx';
    $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', $user, $pass );
            //establish a connection to the database

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username";
    //select from table users only where the username matches username entered

    $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $query->execute( array( ':username'=>$username ) );
    $results = $query->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ); 
    //fetch object in that table

    $stored_hash = $results->password;
    //fetch only password column, this is the hash (used with PHpass)

    $password = $_POST[ 'password' ];
            //take password entered in form
    $hash_obj = new PasswordHash( 8, false );

    $check = $hash_obj->CheckPassword( $password, $stored_hash );
            //check the password entered with CheckPassword class in PHpass

            // HERE IS WHERE I GET LOST

        if ( $check ){ //check if password matches hash

           print_r( "This is a valid user" );
           $_SESSION[ 'logged_in' ] = true; //current session is true

        } else {

           print_r( "Authentication failed, please Try again.");
           $_SESSION[ 'logged_in' ] = false;
                       //current session is false
        }
    ?>
    <?php
    if ( $_SESSION[ 'logged_in' ] == true ){ //okay session is true
            header("Location:http://mywebsite/anotherpage.php"); 
                            //this is supposed to redirect to anotherpage.php

        }else {
            echo "You are not logged in<br/>";
                            //if not successfully logged in, echo this message
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Here is my **anotherpage.php**:

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <?php
    if ( $_SESSION[ 'logged_in' ] == true ){
          echo "You are logged in<br/>";
        }else {
          echo "You are not logged in<br/>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Limiter said

I needed to use output buffering to stop any printing/echoing before using

```
header("Location:/login_check.php");
```

What I did was start the `ob_start()` right after `session_start()`, and `ob_end_flush()` after

```
 if ( $_SESSION[ 'logged_in' ] == true ){ //okay session is true
 header("Location:http://mywebsite/anotherpage.php"); 


   }else {
   echo "You are not logged in<br/>";

   }
   //enter ob_end_flush() here
```

Answer (score 1):

You sent output before redirect with headers, either use output buffering or do the redirect before anything is sent to client

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to do that? I thought I had only outputted one echo after the header in the else statement. I didn't know that was causing the issue.

Comment: all the html between the <?php ?> tags, also any echoing will output stuff.

You could use ob_start(); at start of file and ob_end_flush() at the end to counter that though

Comment: Alright, I'll look into it, if you would help me out with a complete answer though and it works then I could vote up and select your answer and **up** your reputation.

Comment: It is a complete answer, I told you exactly, whats wrong. I am not going to write you code to copy+paste, because that way you'll learn nothing. Sorry, not trying to be rude, but rather help you learn. I would hate when someone just wrote the whole code to me.